# Find last entry with doctrine en DateTimeImmutable sort by YEAR DESC

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How can I have the last entry in my database?
I want to have the last entry from this year (2022,2023...)

I have tested with `$year->format('Y')`, but the result is always `[]` (empty array)

```
$column = "numeroDevis";
$year = new DateTimeImmutable('now').

    public function findLastEntryFromThisYear($column, $year)
{

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->where('d.createdAt = :year')
        ->andWhere('d.'.$column.' IS NOT NULL')
        ->setParameter('year', $year)
        ->orderBy('d.'.$column , 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Comment: I have 3 documents in the database !

Comment: Assuming the field `createdAt` is dateTime, you cannot just compare it against `year`. You need to modify your `where` clause to compare against `year(d.createdAt)` or set a `min` and `max` date within PHP and compare against those accordingly. You could also create a view with an extra `createdAtYear` field that is defined as `year(createdAt)`.

Comment: add doctrineextensions and activate YEAR() function. then select `->where('d.createdAt = YEAR(:year))`